# Setting State updates both objects when only one of the objects is being called using Context API. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have state within my context directory. Two objects that have the same properties but will eventually have different values.

Provider.tsx

```
export const UserStateContext = createContext<any | undefined>(undefined);

function UserProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState<any>({
    userProfile: {
      personInfo: {
        firstName: "Bob",
    },
    tempUserProfile: {
      personInfo: {
        firstName: "Bob",
      }
    }
  });



  return (
    <UserStateContext.Provider
      value={[userState, setUserState]}
    >
      {children}
    </UserStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { UserProvider };
```

Component.tsx

```
function UserDetailsInformation(props: any) {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useContext(
    UserStateContext
  );


  function handleChange(e: any, value: any, child: any, parent: any) {

    let newprop = { ...userState };

    newprop.tempUserProfile.personInfo.firstName = e.target.value;

    setUserState(newprop);

  }


}
```

Both userProfile and tempUserProfile objects are being updated. Both firstNames are now reflected on what the target value was. How do I make it so it only affects the tempUserProfile object?

Comment: Adding `resp` as property values to those two objects does not involve making a copy of the object.

Comment: huh? I will take that part out, I'm talking about the component part

Comment: Your problem is that both are referencing the same (single) object. You don't have two different objects, in other words.

Comment: How is it referencing the same object when I'm referencing one of the objects, newprop.tempUserProfile.personInfo.firstName = e.target.value; Sorry I'm just confused how I'm referencing the same object. I'm getting the same result if I were to create a new state in the provider file with the same structure, rather than within the same state.

Comment: You can check for yourself: `console.log(newprop.userProfile === newprop.tempUserProfile)`

Comment: No, I believe you and I know you're right. I don't understand why that's the case. If I adjust one object, why is it adjusting the other. I guess a better question is how can I make it so I have two different objects?